# querying ssisdb to find the name of packages

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2016

i was querying the ssis catlog to find out the name of all the packages in the catalog.

There are only 6 packages in the Folder1 project,but the query gives  9 records

```
 1. SELECT P.NAME FROM SSISDB.internal.projects PRJ INNER JOIN
    SSISDB.internal.packages P ON
    P.project_version_lsn=PRJ.object_version_lsn WHERE
    PRJ.NAME='Folder1'
```

Does it show the deleted packages from the project as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They aren't deleted, that's part of the historical tracking. You likely wanted a query more similar to

```
SELECT
    F.name AS FolderName
,   P.name AS ProjectName
,   PKG.name AS PackageName
FROM
    ssisdb.catalog.folders AS F
    INNER JOIN 
        SSISDB.catalog.projects AS P
        ON P.folder_id = F.folder_id
    INNER JOIN
        SSISDB.catalog.packages AS PKG
        ON PKG.project_id = P.project_id
ORDER BY
    F.name
,   P.name
,   PKG.name;
```

This reflects that Folders contain Projects and Projects contain Packages so that will provide the exact "address" for a given package.

Answer (score 5):

The `[SSISDB].[internal].[packages]` table and other `internal` tables can contain multiple versions of your packages.

You should use the `catalog` views.

```
SELECT [projects].[name], [packages].[name], *
FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages]
INNER JOIN [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects]
    ON [packages].[project_id] = [projects].[project_id]
ORDER BY [packages].[name]
```

The `catalog` views will return only the active objects.